# Parsing plain text into associative array in PHP

Tags: php

I've been working on this but haven't found any solution yet. I need to parse such string into associative array (PHP)

> Result: ssl_card_number=35********0000 ssl_exp_date=1212
>   ssl_amount=33.55 ssl_invoice_number=0 ssl_description=
>   ssl_company=Some Company ssl_first_name=John ssl_last_name=Cater
>   ssl_avs_address=Test St. ssl_address2= ssl_city=Sandy ssl_state=Utah
>   ssl_avs_zip=84075 ssl_country=United States ssl_phone=
>   ssl_email=johncarter@gmail.com ssl_result=0
>   ssl_result_message=APPROVED
>   ssl_txn_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000
>   ssl_approval_code=123456 ssl_cvv2_response=P ssl_avs_response=X
>   ssl_account_balance=0.00 ssl_txn_time=03/14/2012 06:58:27 PM

This string is what's coming from Merchant Service (the one above contains fake data) so I need to parse it out and reach the values like this

`$card_number = $parsed["ssl_card_number"];`

How can I accomplish it? Note: All the keys start with `ssl_` it can be helpful somewhere maybe.

Comment: Have you tried the `parse_str` function? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)  If that doesn't work, there's always the possibility of using multiple `explode`s.

Comment: exploding may not work due to whitespace issues. using a regular expression would work here, but i am not capable of providing a working one right now. and then there is iterating through the string, looking for the ssl_ substring and copying until the next ssl_ occurs.

Comment: Did you try splitting it on a match of " ssl_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = 'ssl_card_number=35****0000 ssl_exp_date=1212 ssl_amount=33.55 ssl_invoice_number=0 ssl_description= ssl_company=Some Company ssl_first_name=John ssl_last_name=Cater ssl_avs_address=Test St. ssl_address2= ssl_city=Sandy ssl_state=Utah ssl_avs_zip=84075 ssl_country=United States ssl_phone= ssl_email=johncarter@gmail.com ssl_result=0 ssl_result_message=APPROVED ssl_txn_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000 ssl_approval_code=123456 ssl_cvv2_response=P ssl_avs_response=X ssl_account_balance=0.00 ssl_txn_time=03/14/2012 06:58:27 PM';

$result = array();
$arr = preg_split('/\s+ssl_/', $string);
foreach ($arr as $l) {
        $tmp = explode('=', $l, 2);
        $result['ssl_' . $tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: `split()` is deprecated but `explode()` worked just fine and you figuratively saved me life. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok sorry, fixed it, also added the third parameter to explode